# Two Views, One Model - How to handle fetch errors for both?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have one model that is shared between 2 views.
I want to have an error attached to the fetch method that displays an error in both views.

But if I do model.fetch({error:...}), that error would only refer to one view

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trigger an event on the model in error and listen for it in both views.